# Inferring a generic type from its nested type

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a `Fetchable` protocol that contains the location of where to get the objects from as part of its type, and instead of writing the `fetch` function with an explicit type parameter, like this:

```
func fetch<Model: Fetchable>(_ type: Model.Type, path: Model.Path) -> AnyPublisher<[Model], Error> {
   print(path.value)
   // ...
}
```

I would like `Model` to be inferred from the `Model.Path` parameter:

```
func fetch<Model: Fetchable>(path: Model.Path) -> AnyPublisher<[Model], Error> {
   print(path.value)
   // ...
}
```

This is inspired by @RobNapier's approach [here](https://robnapier.net/thats-not-a-number). It's not exactly the same, and so I might be missing salient details to make it work.

Here's what I have:

```
protocol Locatable {
   associatedtype Model
   var value: String { get }
}
```

---

```
protocol Fetchable: Codable {
   associatedtype Path: Locatable where Path.Model == Self
}
```

---

```
struct Message {
   let content: String
}
```

---

```
extension Message: Fetchable, Codable {
   enum Path: Locatable {
      typealias Model = Message
      case forUser(_ userId: String)
      var value: String {
         switch self {
         case .forUser(let userId): return "/user/\(userId)/messages"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I call `fetch`, I get an error **`"Generic parameter 'Model' could not be inferred"`**

```
let pub = fetch(path: Message.Path.forUser("123"))
```

But this works with a `fetch` that accepts the type parameter explicitly (even infers its own Message.Path type):

```
let pub = fetch(Message.self, .forUser("123"))
```

Any idea how (if possible) to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough information to infer, but if we write

```
let pub: AnyPublisher<[Message], Error> = fetch(path: Message.Path.forUser("123"))
```

everything goes well.

**Update:** nested type is just a type it is not dividable, so to help swift to infer parent we need to reverse declaration, like below (tested with Xcode 12.1):

```
func fetch<Path: Locatable>(path: Path) -> 
        AnyPublisher<[Path.Model], Error> where Path.Model: Fetchable {
```

and now your desired expression becomes possible

```
let pub = fetch(path: Message.Path.forUser("123"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @asperi. I understand that, but my question was about whether it's possible to infer from a nested/associated type? Why is it not enough information to infer, is I think what I'd like to understand. Is there a constraint missing? It seems to infer well in the other direction (from `Model` to `Model.Path`)

Comment: See updated part for some possible approach.

Comment: Thanks! That works. Still not sure why the inference didn't work the other way (from inner to outer), but this will do - thanks!